# Terminology for cores in a multicore processor

Tags: multi-core

What is the difference between logical and physical cores in a multicore processor? And is execution core another name for a physical core?

Comment: Which brand?  AMD doesn't have anything like Hyperthreading where as Intel does.  AMD uses physical cores, Intel uses Physical cores and each core can have Hyperthreading.  Edit your question to be specific

Answer (score 0):

A logical core (or logical processor) is a product of Hyper-threading, i.e. running multiple threads in a single core. Thus, having two logical cores means that while you actually have only one physical execution core, it can run two threads at once. Some resources inside the core are duplicated, but not all.

However, in case of a physical core, the entire mechanism till the L1 cache is separate, while the rest (including L2 cache) is shared. Thus, physical cores are faster than logical cores.

AFAIK (someone please correct me if I am wrong), an execution core is indeed a physical core.